# object oriented PHP and Arrays

Tags: php

I have been following a very interesting tutorial that really tested my ability to program Php. I always thought that I am the man but I turn out to be the worse of the worse. Having said that, during the tutorial a requirement to instantiate an object was explained so I typed this code down and do not get me wrong everything works fine no problem at all. The major thing is that I do not really understand how thing work underneath that is why I would like some one to explain to me even more.
my question when you pull a record from the data base using MySQL_fetch_array what and how is the data presented to the receiving variable. for example bellow

```
private static function instantiate($record){
 $object = new self;
   foreach($record as $attribute => $value){
     if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
      $object->$attribute =$value;
     }
   }
   return $object;
 }
```

if I have 3 fields in a table e.g Name, age, address and a value let say Jhone, 23, arizona what will be store in the attribute and what will be store in the Key and where is the index and how do foreeach extract such data from the database like the example above and assign it to the other array. please I do not need any codes my codes are working fine, what I need is a very primitive and clear explanation. and indeed thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Being a programmer is about knowing to accept how little you know.

Comment: You though _you are the man_, but somehow you're still using `mysql_*`? and you've never heard of or read about the `ArrayAccess` interface...??

Comment: Also, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: say i was the man it was just a sense of humor

Comment: @SalimAlmughairi quote it next time so you won't be misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What really helps is to print out stuff in your methods (with `print_r` for instance). For example, try this with your method:

```
private static function instantiate($record){
 print_r($record);
 $object = new self;
 print_r($object);
   foreach($record as $attribute => $value){
     echo "attribute: $attribute, value:$value <br />";
     if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
      $object->$attribute =$value;
     }
   }
   print_r($object);
   die();
   return $object;
 }
```

That way, you can see exactly what is going on with the object, foreach etc.

Comment: `var_dump()` is generally more useful, but that works as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param array $record Record as returned from database
 *
 */
private static function instantiate($record){
    //Create a new instance of this class.
    $object = new self;
    //Iterate the record to find all of the data
    foreach($record as $attribute => $value){
        //If this class has a defined attribute which was found in the record
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
            //Set it to the value from the database.
            $object->$attribute =$value;
        }
    }
    //Return the instance for others to use
    return $object;
}
```

Here's your function right back at you, with documentation.

Comment: i know all what you said i didn't need comments. i think you did not understand my question . the structure of the record the is being pulled how does it being stored in the Key and Value sections of the array. now you have a field Name and Field Age what is the Key and what is the value and where are the attributes stored and what is the index. that what i want to understand and i bet the smart mouth  Elias Van Ootegem cannot answer my questions.

Comment: Key is `age`, value is the value of `age` for that row as fetched from the database. "Attribute" is what we call the variables which are part of objects (just like functions which are part of objects are called **methods**).

Comment: @SalimAlmughairi why don't you just try my suggestion, so you can see all the things you are asking here. Also, try to stay polite (the 'smart mouth' remark). sometimes it is hard to get someone's intention from a written source (in other words, maybe Elias didn't get your sense of humor). We all try our best to answer your question, sometimes with critique, sometimes with comments, sometimes with code. Try to appreciate all approaches.

Comment: thanks for the correction and sorry any way.